# How to determine oldview/newview on back event of navigation view in sencha touch 2

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch-2, back

When the back event fires in a ST2 navigationview how do you determine which view is being navigated away from and which view we're navigating to?

Comment: I was having a similar issue, but I wasn't using the `NavigationView`, just routes and `history.back()` with some buttons. I ended up looking at `MyApp.app.getHistory().getActions()` and comparing it to the new & old views. Not sure how you might use that with the nav view...

Comment: Also, you may want to look at the [documentation for Ext.navigation.View](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-event-pop), specifically the `pop` and `push` events that are fired. You may be able to use those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found another work around for this. I needed to know the old and new views for navigation so that I could change some filters applied to a data store. Here's what I did, on the view that is returning back I added the following code:

```
listeners: {
    deactivate: function() {
        ... do some stuff ...
    }
}
```

Although not a solution to the original problem, this works well for me.